# Context in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Question is about context, it return null on first time running after installing app. Do I need permissions? Earlier versions work. Android developer preview v3 (nexus5)

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static App application;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("APP::", "CREATE");
        application = this;
        Log.e("APPLICATION ::", "" + application);
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return application != null ? application.getBaseContext() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getContext()` before `onCreate()` is called. Don't do that. If possible, don't use a static reference to `App` at all.